# Setup AVM Fritzbox 7320 as Networkbridge

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-bridge, fritzbox

I want to setup my old FritzBox Fon WLAN 7320 as a networkbridge between wifi and ethernet. I have my wifi-router in a different room than my computers and my local network between them. I dont want to buy an Wifistick for each of my computers. So i grabbed an old FritzBox router and tried to configure it as a networkbridge. I followed some instructions on the internet to access the internal linux OS via telnet with root access.
If I enable wifi i can find an "ath0" device in`ifconfig`. I am able to scan for my network with `iwconfig ath0 scan | grep "ESSID"`.
Now I want to connect the device to my wifinetwork.

```
# iwconfig ath0 essid "<MySSID>" mode managed key s:"<MyKey>"
```

I get in result the error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device ath0 ; Invalid argument.
```

and

```
# iwconfig ath0
```

returns

```
ath0      IEEE 802.11ng  ESSID:"<MySSID>"  
          Mode:Master  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: C0:25:06:40:57:B0   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Tx-Power:19 dBm   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:DEB1-AE76-C8B0-61B9-A651-F10F-9861-1ED3 [3]   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=94/94  Signal level=-96 dBm  Noise level=-95 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:769  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

The result is, that my FritzBox does not connect, but creates a new accesspoint named exactly as my default one.
Does anyone has an idea what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. after many many hours of reading and trying, i finally found the solution for that case.

first, you have to create a second ath device which is in managed mode:

> wlanconfig ath create wlandev wifi0 wlanmode sta

then, bring it up:

> ifconfig ath1 up

create a config file for wpa_supplicant, here's an example:

> ap_scan=1
>   ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
>   network={
>         ssid="your router"
>         scan_ssid=1 (or 0 if it doesnt broadcast its ssid)
>         proto=WPA RSN (or whatever...)
>         key_mgmt=WPA-PSK (...you...)
>         pairwise=CCMP TKIP (...need...)
>         group=CCMP TKIP (...for your station)
>         psk="yourkey"
>   }

(you should copy the config to a backup file, wpa_supplicant sometimes remove the file)

now you can connect:

> wpa_supplicant -B -iath1 -c/path/to/yourconfigfile

perhaps you want to attach the new ath1 device to your lan bridge:

> brctl addif lan ath1

if you add it to your lan bridge (what you want to as you described), you should add -blan to the wpa_supplicant command:

> wpa_supplicant -blan -B -iath1 -c/path/to/yourconfigfile

voila!
i hope i saved you many hours of lifetime :-)